# Simulating hospital in Java (Priority Queue)

Tags: java, oop, queue, priority-queue

Im currently learning ADT's in school and for an assignment I have to simulate an ER in a hospital. I currently have my patient class as follows:

```
public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient>{

    private String name;
    private int condition;

    public Patient( String n, int c ){
        this.name = name;
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    public int boundary(int condition) {
        if (condition > 17){
            return 17;
        }
        else if (condition < 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        return condition;
    }

    public int compareTo( Patient other ) {
        if( this.condition < that.condition ) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if( this.condition > that.condition ) {
            return +1;
        }
        else {
            return this.name.compareTo(that.name);
        }    
    }
}
```

And I need to now make a class called ER()... One of many methods i have to implement have the conditions as follows:

```
public void addPatient(String name, int severity, Date time)
// Purpose: adds a person to the waiting list in the emergency 
//          room.  
// Preconditions: name is not null
//                severity is an integer in the range [1,17]
//                time is the current time
// Postconditions: the person is added to the emergency room
//                 waiting list.  The "priority" in the list is 
//                 based on severity (1 being least important and
//                 17 being most important) first and for patients
//                 with equal severity, based on time (FIFO).
```

My question is, where exactly would I create each patient (assign name and condition severity) and could someone help me with (please explain cuz i wanna learn, im not asking for direct code or answers) the prioritizing aspect and how to prioritize patients with same severity by time of arrival?

Thanks in advance for any help or input everyone!

Comment: Is the `patient` class given to you as a template or you code it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue will give you ideas on what a priority queue is, does and how to implement it. You should create and add patients to your ER in your main() method.

Comment: @TheocharisK. i coded it... so the design could very well be improper or inefficiently. Im hoping i designed it correctly?!?!?! feel free to let me know how i did! PS: i do get an error on the "that" in my compareTo method, although i was gonna tackle that error later on!

Comment: You got an error on `that` keyword because simply there is no such keyword in Java. You should replace it with `other`. Also a good tip is to add a `Date` variable to your `Patient` class where you can save the time of arrival of each patient, so you can compare them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with creating specific controller like `FrontDeskController`, and in this class create method e.g `register`/`checkIn`, `checkOut`. You will insert/remove all patients data here and collect all data in single `Collection` which you think its suitable for your case.

To prioritizing queue, if it possible separate the `Collection` you want to process, so you must sort with simple sort algorithm e.g quicksort and pass the sort data to another collection e.q `Queue`, `Stack`. i think this method good to be in `ER` Class.

Comment: so essentially you are saying make a seperate class which will handle the time of arrival and the date class information?

Comment: what do you mean by date class information?
When patient arrive get the time of her/his arrival, save it in patient properties, let say Patient class have `Date timeArrival`.

Then in ER Class you have to sort all the Patient data by Date or by its condition value

Comment: would  this class extend Patient?

Comment: `ER` shouldn't extend `Patient`. `Patient` should be treat as POJO model and `ER` as Controller. add `private java.util.Date timeArrival` in `Patient` class, it should be enough, and assign the value when `register`